# In ASP.Net MVC how do you generate facebook links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

In ASP.Net MVC, how do you generate the following link?

```
<a class="facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=HTTP://myreallycoolsite.com/somegroup/somechildgroup/some_title/">some_title</a>
```

The current page is

```
HTTP://myreallycoolsite.com/somegroup/somechildgroup/some_title/
```

and it needs to be used as a parameter of the external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in razor:

```
@{ 
    // you can inline this instead
    var Param = Url.Encode(Url.Action("action", "controller", new{ /*params*/ });
        ^^^^^
    // or for the current page's URL (hat tip @Dismissile)
    Param = Url.Encode(Request.Url.ToString());
}
<a class="facebook"
   rel="nofollow" 
   target="_blank" 
   href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@Param">some_title</a>
                                              ^^^^^^
```

If you're not using Razor, it looks like this (or at least close to this):

```
<%
    // you can inline this instead
    var Param = Url.Encode(Url.Action("action", "controller", new{ /*params*/ });
        ^^^^^
    // or for the current page's URL (hat tip @Dismissile)
    Param = Url.Encode(Request.Url.ToString());
%>
<a class="facebook"
   rel="nofollow" 
   target="_blank" 
   href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<%=Param%>">some_title</a>
                                                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Could you have avoided encoding by using Param = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri ?

Answer (score 2):

Create the link as normal and put @Request.Url.ToString() in it. If you need to dynamically put the some_title text in there then you will need to do one of a few different things. If it is part of the route, then you could pull it from RouteData. If it is the title of your page you could probably use ViewBag.Title. If it is completely arbitrary you might just need to use a regex.

```
<a class="facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@Request.Url.ToString()">some_title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  <a href="#" 
    onclick="
       window.open(
       'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
       'facebook-share-dialog', 
       'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
       Share on Facebook
   </a>
```